# Can I wrap two columns and move one of the columns up with position:relative, and have the wrapper not have any extra space on the bottom?

Tags: css

If I have some HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
 <div class="first">&nbsp;</div>
 <div class="second">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
```

And some CSS:

```
.wrapper{
 font-size:0px;
 padding-top:200px;
 background:rgba(255,0,0,.2);
}
.first{
 display:inline-block;
 width:25%;
 height:300px;/*Actually the height will be dependent on text.*/
 background:black;
 position:relative;
 bottom:100px;
}
.second{
 display:inline-block;
 width:75%;
 height:100px;/*Height actually dependent on text*/
 background:green;
}
```

**NOTE: The heights are not really fixed. They are dependent on text.**

[See JSFiddle here.](https://jsfiddle.net/aobzfjb5/)

How do I make the wrapper only wrap the contents and not wrap the space that remains when you move the column up? I want there to be no pink underneath the black column.

I tried every combination of `overflow:auto/hidden/visible/etc` I could think of, and I googled and found information that it's not possible to do with `position:absolute`, but I couldn't find anything regarding `position:relative`.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try adding `margin-bottom:-100px;` to this code(to .first class).

Comment: Perfect, thanks! I'll have to look up how negative margins work later.

Comment: Well, to be honest, I am not a big fan of negative margins, but sometimes they do the dirty work.

Comment: Yeah I'm not a fan of things that semantically make no sense. But it works!